# PPL tag, but there is not a Private Pilot License in the US

Tags: discussion, tags

I know this is harping on semantics, but there is no such thing as a Private Pilot's License in the USA. And while this might be common vernacular, wouldn't it be more appropriate to encourage users to use the correct terminology? I think there is a distinction between license and certificate and the phrase "license" does not appear in any FAA publication. This is just a pet peeve of mine so feel free to down vote, but I think its worth consideration. Tag suggestions might be [certification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certification) or [ppc](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ppc).

Comment: Actually, the private pilot's certificate IS a private pilot's licence[sic], as defined by ICAO (if I'm not mistaken, a quick google turned up some documents suggesting this to be true) of which the US is a member state.

Comment: The difference is that ICAO is not a governing body. They set standards, countries provide regulations to try to meet those standards. This might make a good question.

Comment: True, but 'license' is still more common than 'certificate' worldwide, and it doesn't change the fact that a US private pilot's certificate is an ICAO private pilot's license, so saying it's incorrect is a wrong except for the context of the FAA. I just think it's wrong to rename something on an international site to match the terminology of a national governing body.

Comment: I didn't suggest renaming it, or eliminating it. I just think there needs to be a distinction. This also applies to other international tags. I think some sort of synonym would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 3):

I agree!

Looking at the questions tagged [ppl](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ppl) I actually don't even see one that would really require the tag at all, as the questions are about regulations or training, not the actual certificate.

In fact, I can't really think of any questions that would be specific to a certain type of license.

There are questions about the **privilege** that a license confers, or the rules about **obtaining** a license, but those are regulation type questions.

I say that we just remove the tag altogether and make sure that the questions tag the appropriate regulatory authorities regulations or [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training).

If there does turn out to be a need, we should probably just create [private-pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private-pilot) (along with commercial, atp, etc.) since that would be appropriate world-wide (even the FAA PTS refers repeatedly to "private pilot" without the word certificate attached).

Also, see the Meta question [Tags airman-certification and flight-training are inconsistent](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/tags-airman-certification-and-flight-training-are-inconsistent) for thoughts on how certification questions should be tagged.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will study it.

Comment: private-/commercial-/airline-transport-pilot is fine with me too, complies nicely with the general 'avoid abbreviations'-policy too :)

Answer (score 2):

It's true that there's no such thing as a "private pilot's license" in the FAA's terms, but there is such a thing as a "private pilot" and people ask me about my "pilot's license" because it's simply a more natural term, presumably by comparison to "driver's license".

Outside the US, "certificates" are usually "licenses" and PPL is a very common abbreviation so just removing it completely is probably not the best approach.

Whatever we settle on as the general "pilot's license" or "pilot training" tag, [ppl](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ppl) would be a useful synonym at least (see this [related question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/tags-airman-certification-and-flight-training-are-inconsistent)). PPC doesn't mean anything to me in an aviation context.

Finally, if we need to separate private pilot issues from others then we always have the option of something like [private-pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private-pilot), [commercial-pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-pilot), [airline-pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-pilot) or [airline-transport-pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-transport-pilot).

Comment: airline-*transport*-pilot perhaps, to keep the resemblance to the ATPL?

Comment: I'm not voting for [tag:ppc], I was just brainstorming ideas. I could see it used as a synonym, which would help clarify the proper terminology.

Comment: @roe Yes, that could make sense, I added it to my answer

Comment: @Magnetoz That's OK, I understood you were just putting it out there for comments

Comment: @Magnetoz; only problem I see is, it isn't proper anywhere but in the US. Whereas calling it a license is at least sorta proper in the US too (by ICAO association if nothing else), as well as proper everywhere else

Comment: @roe, a user in the US who wants to further research Pilot "Licenses", will have a hard time finding that information in the regs and elsewhere. My concern would be to somehow link the "License" terminology to "Certificate" so that questioners get the most precise answers. I realize this is an issue specific to the USA, but it seems a lot of effort is being had to provide answers specific to region.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `PPL` is a an internationally accepted moniker. I haven't done any research into whether a `ppl` tag is appropriate for any of the questions, but the fact remains there is a PPL pretty much everywhere (at least colloquially in the US, it's not uncommon to refer to a private pilot's certificate as a private pilot's license), as it is the name defined by ICAO. I don't think "private pilot's certificate" is used anywhere but the US, though. Calling this 'correct' terminology is, in a majority vote, probably wrong.

So either keep `PPL`, or get rid of it, but in my humble opinion, I don't think there should be a `PPC` tag. That said, I have to agree with Lnafziger that I can't really think of any questions where the tag would be appropriate, so probably better to remove it altogether.